# vue-dplayer does not load video after passing the url in the options

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I tried to get vue-dplayer working, but after using the official configuration the video does not load or play. When I inspect the code that is generated, I see the url on the page.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <d-player @play="play" :options="video" ref="player"></d-player>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import VueDPlayer from 'vue-dplayer'
  import 'vue-dplayer/dist/vue-dplayer.css'

  export default {
    name: 'play',
    components: {
      'd-player':VueDPlayer
    },
    data () {
      return {
        video:{
          url: 'http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4',
          pic: '../img/icons/01.jpg'
        }
      }
    },
    methods:{
      play(){
        console.log('play callback')
      }
    },
    mounted(){
      const player = this.$refs.player.dp
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: For future questions, please work on creating a better title. I assume the system prompted you to tell what the actual problem was, rather than a generic "x doesn't work", but adding "I can't find anything to ask" to the title does not make that any better.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is simply that you are not using an options object with the right keys. You are required to have an options object with a `video` key in it, but instead you are passing an object with the `url` and `pic` key. Simply wrap it in an extra object so it can find the options.

```
data () {
 return {
   options {
     video:{
       url: 'http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4',
       pic: '../img/icons/01.jpg'
     }
   }
  }
}
```

```
<d-player @play="play" :options="options" ref="player"></d-player>
```